# Using CROSS JOIN SEQUENCE to produce large duplicated tables

Tags: sql, azure, azure-databricks, databricks-sql, azure-notebooks

I have the following in an Azure notebook (databricks sql):

```
CREATE TABLE my_new_big_table AS
  SELECT t.*
  FROM my_table t
  CROSS JOIN VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10) v(i);
```

This duplicates the `my_table`, 10 times, however how can I use a loop (`SEQUENCE, EXPLORE`) to create iterations of 100, 1000 etc?

Comment: You don't use a loop. You cross join with an ad-hoc table. Right now you create the rows of the ad-hoc table with the `VALUES` clause. Instead you can use `SEQUENCE` to create an array and `EXPLODE` to convert this array into rows. Please try it yourself first, before coming here to ask for help.

Comment: Does [`sequence`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/functions/sequence) function help? `sequence(1, 100)`? See if you can join the table with array using `explode`? i.e. `explode(sequence(1, 100))`

Comment: Yes I tried already CROSS JOIN SEQUENCE(0, 100);

Comment: If only SQL,use CROSS JOIN VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10) v(i) CROSS JOIN VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10) v2(i) CROSS JOIN VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10) v3(i) - create 1000 iterations.

Comment: Depending of the version of SQL Server you have, you can use GENERATE_SERIES (n, m) to generate a serie of numbers between n and m boudary values of the interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my sample data:

[image]

With your code, I got the output like below which have every row repeated 10 times.

[image]

To do the above dynamically, you can use `range(start,end)` like below.

```
%sql
CREATE TABLE result2 AS
  SELECT t.* 
  FROM sample1 as t
  CROSS JOIN (select * from range(0,10)) v(i);
select * from result2;
```

**My Result:**

[image]

**(Or)**

Use `sequence(start,end)` with `explode()` as discussed by community in comments.

```
create table result3 as
SELECT t.* 
FROM sample1 as t 
CROSS JOIN (select explode(sequence(1,10))) v(i);
select * from result3;
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, this is more or less what I wanted. I would have liked however that ther "id" doesnt contain duplicates, so maybe replace all entries in the "id" with something unique, like the row number.